# Android: Google map error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I am having problem integrating google map in my application. Whenever I debug, it shows error related to inflating class fragment. I have tried every solutions from stackoverflow and other internet resources but none of them works and I am frustrated. Here is the relevant part of my Activity class.

```
public class Dashboard extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
}
```

Here is the xml.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/the_map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
map:cameraTilt="45"
map:cameraZoom="14"
/>
```

Here is the Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.golfscorecard.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.golfscorecard.Dashboard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="/I have valid api here/" />

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

LOGCAT:

```
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.view9.golfscorecard/com.view9.golfscorecard.Dashboard}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at com.view9.golfscorecard.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:17)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    ... 11 more
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-19 14:00:29.553: E/AndroidRuntime(13285):    ... 21 more
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the posted xml  `activity_dashboard.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
public class Dashboard extends ActionBarActivity {
```

to

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity {
```

`ActionBar` is available natively from api level 11. So there is no need for `ActionbarActivity`.

Use of `MapFragment` is right.

Comment: @bipin its because you used `MapFragment` not `SupportMapFragment` in which case you should extend standard `Activity`.

Comment: @bipin if you use `SupportMapFragment` and want to support map api level 11 and below then extend `ActionBarActivity`. note `ActionbarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Since you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` Use `SupportMapFragment`

or as your `android:minSdkVersion="12"` you can direcly use `android.app.Fragment` in that case you can use your current xml.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/the_map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
map:cameraTilt="45"
map:cameraZoom="14" />
```

Comment: @bipi extend standard `Acivity`. action bar is available from api level 11 no need for ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kindly change and check the following codes.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

and

```
public class MapScreen extends FragmentActivity {

       private GoogleMap mMap;  

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
      mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).getMap();
      mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     }
}
```

You need to have googleplayservice library project. and your project version should be support google api's.